# Using a Sass Placeholder With a Variable

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to loop out a series of heading font sizes with a variable for each heading level and I am getting stuck with declaring the variable name as a placeholder.

**_variables.scss**

```
$h1-font-size: 2.5rem;
$h2-font-size: 2.25rem;
$h3-font-size: 2rem;
```

**_heading-loops.scss**

```
@for $i from 1 through 3 {
   h#{$i} {
      font-size: $#{i}-font-size;
   }
}
```

**Expect CSS Output**

```
h1 { font-size: 2.5rem; }
h2 { font-size: 2.25rem; }
h3 { font-size: 2rem; }
```

I would've thought this would work out, but unfortunatley it throws the following error:

```
error scss/utilities/functions/_headings.scss (Line 37: Invalid CSS 
after "      font-size: ": expected expression (e.g. 1 px, bold), was 
"$#{i}-font-size;")
```

I would love some advice on this cause I've been scratching my head over it for way too long, thanks in advance.

Comment: can u try my below answer into your `_variables.scss` and `_heading-loops.scss` and check if it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With small workaround using your own code, i was able to get the expected output.

```
$h1: 2.5rem;
$h2: 2.25rem;
$h3: 2rem;

$htags: $h1, $h2, $h3;

@for $i from 1 through length($htags) {
  h#{$i} {
    font-size: nth($htags, $i);
  }
}
```

i tried it in https://www.sassmeister.com/, it works perfectly

Note: Instead of generating the variables names using interpolation you can create a list and use the `nth` method to get the values :)